# How to split screen in two horizontal DIVs both with their own scrollbars? (example link given)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was just wondering how it is possible to make something similar to this:
http://folderstudio.com/

I'm running on Wordpress and am making my website through a child theme. It would have a fixed header too.

I managed to have individual scrollbars for each divs by using `overflow: scroll` coupled with some `height: *XXX*px` but I would like to be achieve that with `height: 100%`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create two `divs` each with its own `overflow-y: scroll` like this http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ns3u7uf5/9/

here is divs at 100% http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ns3u7uf5/11/

**html**

```
<div class="box-1">
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="box-2">
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Tsukasa already figured this out. He wanted to know how to use this with a `100% height`

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And then you can just use a `100% height`